# Numpy append 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a bunch of 2d arrays shape `(32,32)` that I want to be apart of a larger 3d array.

I don't know how many 2d arrays there are so they must be appended.

I've tried stacking but that only works for the first 2 arrays.

What I want is to have a big array of shape `(0, 32, 32)` that when I append the first 2d array will become `(1, 32, 32)` then `(2, 32, 32)` but so far nothing has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reshaping the 2d arrays into 3d arrays with one dimension in the axis 0:

```
big_array = np.zeros((1,32,32))

2d_array = np.ones((32,32))

big_array = np.append(big_array, 2d_array.reshape(1,32,32), axis=0)
big_array.shape
>>> (2,32,32)
```